# DateDiff en c# (para semanas y meses)

Tags: date, vb

Tengo este código en visual basic. Y no se como obtener los mismos resultados en C# ya que no existe el diff alli. Solamente puedo hacer con el cálculo de horas. ¿Como puedo obtener los resultados en semanas y meses?

```
    Dim fechaActual As Date = Date.Today
    Dim fechaFin As Date = New DateTime(2020, 12, 31)
    Dim meses, semanas, horas As Integer
    meses = DateDiff("m", fechaActual, fechaFin)
    semanas = DateDiff("ww", fechaActual, fechaFin)
    horas = DateDiff("h", fechaActual, fechaFin)
    Console.WriteLine("Fecha actual: " & fechaActual)
    Console.WriteLine("Fecha fin: " & fechaFin)
    Console.WriteLine("Faltan: " & meses & "meses")
    Console.WriteLine("Faltan: " & semanas & "" & "semanas")
    Console.WriteLine("Faltan: " & horas & "horas"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer es agregar la referencia **Microsoft.VisualBasic** para poder usar la funcion > Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateDiff

Ejemplo:

```
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2017,5,20);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Today;  
        long difMonth = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateDiff(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval.Month, d1, d2);
```

Comment: excelente me funciono!!! muchas gracias